# To select the encrypted password from mysql

Tags: php

I need to select only the password from the table with the specific username entered through the log in form. I store the password in the encrypted form in the mysql table. So I need to compare the given password and stored password and have to print "logged in successfully". else password is incorrect. this is my code.Now I am getting the output as "1Resource id #4".can any one plz help...

```
mysql_select_db($dbName);
$user_name=$_POST['name'];
$pswd=$_POST['pswd'];
$res        = mysql_query("select * from xxx where Name='$user_name'");
$row        = mysql_num_rows($res);
echo $row;
$encpass=mysql_query("SELECT password FROM xxx WHERE Name = '$user_name'");
$result1= mysql_fetch_array($encpass);
echo $result1;
if($row>0)
{
//echo 'hi';
   if(md5($pswd)==$result1)
       {
         echo 'hi';
         echo "you have successfully signed in!!!";
         //echo $name   =   $row['Name'];
         //header("location:check.html");
       }
}

else
echo "you are not a member";
```

Answer (score 3):

You are over complicating this. You don't need to retrieve the passwords from the database.  You just need to see if you can select a row which has the username and password that were submitted.

First - get the username and password from the user and get them in the form that matches however you have stored it.

```
$username = $_POST['name'];
$password = my_password_encryption_function( $_POST['pswd'] );
```

Second - set up your SQL. Use a prepared statement to protect against SQL injection attacks. Your current approach is unsafe and allows users to change the passwords of arbitary users (among other things).

```
$preparedStatement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE Name = :name AND password = :password');
$preparedStatement->execute(array(':name' => $username, ':password' => $password));
$rows = $preparedStatement->fetchAll();
```

Third - just count the rows returned. If you get one result, the password matched. If you get zero results, the password didn't match.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the resultset as an array, you still have to traverse it.

Just change:

```
if(md5($pswd)==$result1)
```

To:

```
if(md5($pswd)==$result1[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as telling you what slipbull said - "You are printing the resultset as an array, you still have to traverse it." - I'll also tell you that your code is currently ***VERY*** dangerous.

You are sticking the user's passed data straight into an SQL query. They can take over your database by doing that.

Instead, pass the parameter through `mysql_real_escape_string()` BEFORE doing anything with the data.

**Fix this before you do ANYTHING else!!**